# Auto Complete Date Feature in Android

Tags: android, autocomplete

I'm working on an application where need to complete date automatic/suggest while writing. Thing is user can type other text as well so how to sure when he start writing for date.

For reference: I have found similar feature on [slack](https://slack.com/) app.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Add `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` view. In one of it's methods for example `beforeTextChanged` or `onTextChanged` get the last entered word (or char sequence - it's up to you to decide which part of entered text you want to check). Apply regular expression to it to check if it looks like date or not. Again it's up to you to decide what looks like date and what is not. If it looks like date - provide users with UI for auto completion or autocomplete by our own. Don't forget to move cursor to the end of autocompleted text using `EditText.setSelection()` method.